# Overwrite ko.computed value

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have this code here

```
  orderTotal = ko.computed(function () {

        return parseFloat($("#PurchaseDomainSuffix option:selected").text().match(/[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?/g)) || 0;
    }
```

which is taking the numeric value out of a string on page load. (loaded from a dropdownlist) But when the list is changed I cannot figure out how to update the orderTotal value.

I am new to knockout I was looking into the write function for a ko.computed.  Not sure if im looking in the correct direction.
How would I overwrite the value from page load with a new value after the dropdownlist is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout has pretty cool support for dropdowns.

You can use the `options` binding to generate the list, and the value option to make the right selection. Here's a quick example.

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.list = [{
      name: "Breakfast",
      time: 'Morning'
    },
    {
      name: "Lunch",
      time: 'Noon'
    },
    {
      name: "Dinner",
      time: 'Evening'
    }
  ];

  self.selectedItem = ko.observable();

  self.selectedComputed = ko.computed(function() {
    var selectedItem = self.selectedItem();
    return "I'll eat at " + selectedItem;

  });


}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="options: list, value: selectedItem, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'time'"></select>
<br>
<span data-bind="text: selectedItem"></span>
<br>
<span data-bind="text: selectedComputed"></span>
```

Comment: That does make alot of sense. But the values in the dropdown are populated by a database pull before pageload. Which do change now and then. So hardcoding them in the list is not an option.

Comment: You can use an `observableArray` to contain the list. I just used this as an example.

Comment: Ended up changing the computed to an observable and just running a .orderTotal(value) to update it.